# Can I post my Bachelor Thesis for correction?

Tags: discussion

I am writing my Bachelor thesis in English, but I'm not a native English speaker.  Am I allowed to post my Bachelor thesis on StackOverflow?

The reasons I want to do so:

1. I write in English
2. Professional correction costs a lot.
3. Even if I choose professional correction they can fix typos but not the semantics because the thesis is about C++ and an algorithm.

Comment: You know, editing this question for grammar is wrong.

Answer (score 10):

Highly unlikely.

We can do code reviews and such, but generally only if someone keeps it very short. An entire thesis is generally outside the realm of most of the people on StackOverflow.

Comment: the thesis is about 15-20 pages.and it is not "so" complicated.

Comment: 15-20 pages of material for someone to peruse through on StackOverflow is generally WAY too much. You would be much more likely to go to a traditional discussion forum or perhaps an English-oriented writing site.

Answer (score 5):

I do not think that SO is the right place to do that as it is an Q&A site. Apart from that, there might be some issues with you publishing the content of your Bachelor thesis before handing it in. Is this allowed by your university?

Answer (score 5):

Look, I'm as much of a repwhore as the next guy. That, and I'm bloody addicted to this site. That being said, I'm not reading a 20 page thesis and giving feedback on this site just for the upvotes.

Moreover, I prefer having a hardcopy when reviewing papers and the like so that I can write all over them. To do a proper review, I'd need to have a cup of coffee with you and yell at you for how wrong you are (I can't help it, I enjoy making other people cry).

The best thing you can do is find somebody knowledgeable about the topic that likes you (I know that's a hard proposition), hand them the paper, buy them coffee and probably something out of the bake case (I do love vanilla scones), and have them review it.

For the record, I had my thesis reviewed by a guy who was my best man. And that required a case of Guinness and pizza as an offering.

Comment: Had the thesis survived the Guinness?

Comment: The thesis was written primarily while imbibing Guinness, so having the review done with Guinness around was really the only logical choice. And my diploma is hanging on the wall behind me. Oh, sweet Guinness, where would I be without you?

Comment: Your prof was Irish?

Comment: @John: My prof? My whole bloody school. We had a library dedicated to Irish history. It was in Boston, after all :)

Comment: That explains a lot! ;)

Answer (score 4):

Note that doing so would make your Bachelor thesis licensed under [CC-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/).    Other folks would be allowed to

- Share — to copy, distribute and transmit the work
- Remix — to adapt the work

...although they would also have to share alike and attribute it to you.  Probably not real concern, but it is something to consider.  Your university may have guidelines on the licensing subject too.

Comment: +1: I was going to answer the same thing, he would be forfeiting (is this the right word?) rights

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm... I don't think so, at least not for language corrections. The StackOverflow network is for technical questions, not for spelling/grammar unless it's in a code context (i.e. Variable names). I guess that the question will get closed as Not Programming Related rather quickly.

Of course, questions to the technical facts are always possible and welcome, but as said, proofreading does not have a place anywhere on the 4 SO Sites.

Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 3):

Anything over 5 pages will be transferred to dead trees if I need to read it. And I hate to waste dead trees to just answer someone's questions.

Still, what you could do is post the thesis on your website with an option for visitors to comment on it. Then put the link to your online thesis in your profile and don't spam people with it. Just refer to your thesis in this topic so anyone who won't waste dead trees to read it will still be welcome to read it and provide feedback to you.

Comment: +1 for mentioning "Anything over 5 pages will be transferred to dead trees if I need to read it".